# modifying an element in master page based on action in content page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Link element in the Master Page. This element is initially invisible.
Upon a certain action in one of the content page, I need to make that Link element visible.
I am looking into ways of how this could be done. Can I do it from my Controller method or will I have to do it via ajax?

Comment: The "certain action" is an action in which are involved the server or only the client??

Comment: so the content page calls a method on controller. This controller has logic that will decide either the link on master page should be visible now.

Comment: yes, but I think your action returns a json or something with the boolean parameter, then (if you are using ajax) in the function that you call with the `success` parameter you pass that boolean result and change the link with css and javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manipulate the UI in mvc you need to use javascript. If your "certain action" are involved with the server I think you need to use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "yourController/yourAction",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json){
        var domEl = document.getElementById('theIdOfyourLink');

        if(json.show){
            domEl.style.display = 'block';
        }else{
            domEl.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
});
```

If you action are only involved with the client you can use only javascript. At the end you can playing with css to make visible or not your link:

```
var yourfun = function(show){
    var domEl = document.getElementById('theIdOfyourLink');

    if(show){
        domEl.style.display = 'block';
    }else{
        domEl.style.display = 'none';
    }

}
```

Comment: Added comment in response to your comment. Can you pleae take a look and let me know what could be better approach

Answer (score 0):

[Find control on master pages](https://web.archive.org/web/20140523040144/http://netindonesia.net/blogs/haritianp/archive/2010/07/18/master-pages-and-findcontrol-in-asp-net-2-0.aspx)

Found this, might help.
From your code behind you can just find the control, cast it, and manipulate it.

```
Panel pnlWelcome2 = this.Master.FindControl("pnlWelcome") as Panel;
```

Comment: Remember this is MVC and not web-forms

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use TempData or ViewData.

Your 'certain action' in your controller could be like

```
public ActionResult MyCertainAction()
{
   TempData["ShowLink"] = true;
}
```

Then, you masterpage could have the following

```
@if (TempData["ShowLink"] != null && (bool)TempData["ShowLink"]) 
{
   <a href="#">My link</a>
}
```